# Elasticsearch-groovy bulk requests

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

According to the [elasticsearch-groovy documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-groovy/blob/master/docs/quickstart.asciidoc#bulk-document-operations), there is an example of a BulkRequest. Instead of adding the requests and executing in one large statement, like the example in the docs, I want to build up a `BulkRequest` or an Array of `ActionRequests` (IndexRequest, DeleteRequest, ...) step by step and execute the whole Array in a bulk.

I tried the following:

```
@Grab(group='org.elasticsearch', module='elasticsearch-groovy', version='1.7.0')

import org.elasticsearch.client.Client
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder

import org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequest
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.*
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest

Node node = nodeBuilder().settings {
                cluster {
                    name = "lemato_cluster"
                  }
                  node {
                    client = true
                  }
            }.node()

// Get a usable Node Client                
Client client = node.client

BulkRequest indexBulk = []

indexBulk.add new IndexRequest().with {
    index "my_index"
    type "my_type"
    id "1"
    source {
      user = "kimchy"
      postDate = "2013-01-30"
      message = "trying out Elasticsearch"
      nested {
        details {
          here = 123
          timestamp = new Date()
        }
      }
    }
}

indexBulk.add new IndexRequest().with {
    index "my_index"
    type "my_type"
    id "2"
    source {
      user = "kimchy2"
      postDate = "2013-02-30"
      message = "trying out Elasticsearch for my 2nd set"
      nested {
        details {
          here = 123
          timestamp = new Date()
        }
      }
    }
}

BulkResponse br = client.bulk(indexBulk).actionGet()
println br.getItems()

node.close()
```

This works fine, but unfortunately only the first IndexRequest is executed, the second one is discarded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to do this, is to use the `BulkRequestBuilder`:

```
@Grab(group='org.elasticsearch', module='elasticsearch-groovy', version='1.7.0')

import org.elasticsearch.client.Client
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder

import org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequest
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.*
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest

Node node = nodeBuilder().settings {
                cluster {
                    name = "lemato_cluster"
                  }
                  node {
                    client = true
                  }
            }.node()

// Get a usable Node Client                
Client client = node.client

import static org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.*;

BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

// either use client#prepare, or use Requests# to directly build index/delete requests
bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
        .setSource{
            user = "kimchy"
            postDate = new Date()          
            message = "just a post"
        }
    );

bulkRequest.add(client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "2")
        .setSource{
            user = "kimchy"
            postDate = new Date()           
            message = "another post"
        }
    );

BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing it is like this:

```
@Grab(group='org.elasticsearch', module='elasticsearch-groovy', version='1.7.0')

import org.elasticsearch.client.Client
import org.elasticsearch.node.Node
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder

import org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequest
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.*
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest

Node node = nodeBuilder().settings {
                cluster {
                    name = "lemato_cluster"
                  }
                  node {
                    client = true
                  }
            }.node()

// Get a usable Node Client                
Client client = node.client

BulkResponse response = client.bulk {
  add new IndexRequest().with {            <--- call "add" and then specify the list of request to add
    index "my_index"
    type "my_type"
    id "1"
    source {
      user = "kimchy"
      postDate = "2013-01-30"
      message = "trying out Elasticsearch"
      nested {
        details {
          here = 123
          timestamp = new Date()
        }
      }
    }
  },
  new IndexRequest().with {                <--- adding the second request
    index "my_index"
    type "my_type"
    id "2"
    source {
      user = "kimchy2"
      postDate = "2013-02-30"
      message = "trying out Elasticsearch for my 2nd set"
      nested {
        details {
          here = 123
          timestamp = new Date()
        }
      }
    }
  },

  ...  <--- add your other IndexRequest, UpdateRequest or DeleteRequest separated by commas.

}.actionGet()

println response.getItems()

node.close()
```

Comment: thanks, but what i actually want is to build up the array step by step. Something like: `myactionRequestArray.add( new client.index ... ); some other code; myactionRequestArray.add(new client.index... ); some other code ; response = myactionRequestArray.execute().actionGet()`